# How to host a webpage if the index.html is in “public” folder

Tags: github, github-pages

I have tried to host a static web page that is developed using vuejs. But i have my **index.html** is in the **/public** folder.

At first, when GitHub gave me the URL, that was just loading the content from `readme.md`, I supposed it was because I didn't have any index.html in the root folder.

```
https://aakashbashyal21.github.io/JobListing/
```

Later I created a dummy `index.html` in the root directory to redirect to the public folder by adding:

```
<meta
  http-equiv="refresh"
  content="0; url=https://aakashbashyal21.github.io/joblisting/public/index.html"
/>
```

But after adding the index.html now it gives me an error as **Site, not found.**

I have set my repository as:

[image]

Is there any option to host a webpage if the index.html is in the “public” folder? Alternatively is there any other option for doing that without doing any re-direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) for pointing me in the right direction with the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64238624/3811265), finally I was able to solve these issues. So, I wanted to document the solution with the step I did to figure out this issue.

Step 1. Firstly, I created a `vue.config.js` in the project root directory and Set the correct **publicPath** in `vue.config.js`.

Explanation extracted from https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages

> If you are deploying to `https://<USERNAME>.github.io/`, you can omit
> **publicPath** as it defaults to "/".
> If you are deploying to `https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>/`, (i.e. your repository is at `https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>`),
> set **publicPath** to `"/<REPO>/"`.

For example, if your repo name is "my-project", your vue.config.js should look like this:

```
// vue.config.js file to be place in the root of your repository

module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/my-project/'
    : '/'
}
```

Step 2: Build my project using `npm build`

Step 4: Removed the dist directory from the project’s `.gitignore file`

Step 3: Run `git add dist`

Step 4: Run `git commit -m 'adding dist subtree'`

Step 5: Use subtree push to send it to the `gh-pages` branch on GitHub. `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` Source: https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490

Credits:

1. https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-your-vue-app-to-github-pages-897136799e19

Answer (score 2):

The only folder [mentioned by the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site) is docs:

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/publishing-source-folder-drop-down.png]

So you might have to:

- rename public to docs
- or generate the site in a separate branch

See as an example "[Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-your-vue-app-to-github-pages-897136799e19)" from [Matt Maribojoc](https://twitter.com/learnvueco):

> One of the easiest ways to do this is to create a separate `gh-pages` branch on your repository. Our end goal is for this branch to contain just our build folder — which for a lot of projects, will be dist.
>
> And we can do this by using this `gh-pages` branch as a [subtree](https://gist.github.com/SKempin/b7857a6ff6bddb05717cc17a44091202) of our master branch.

Comment: that example you were referring suggest to build a project using `npm build`, isn't there any other way to serve the index.html without building them?

Comment: @aakash As long as the index.html is in a dedicated branch, it will work too